# Is there any possibility to get the currentStockLevel from this method?

Tags: java, methods, void

I need the currentStockLevel for another void Method in java, is there any possibility to get it? 
I think no, because of void right?

```
public void receive (int currentStock)
{
    String outLine;
    if (currentStockLevel > 0)
        outLine = productCode;
    {
        outLine = ". Current Stock: " + currentStockLevel;
        outLine += " Current Stock changed from " + currentStockLevel;
        currentStockLevel += currentStock;
        outLine += " to " + currentStockLevel;
        int storeCost = wholeSalePrice * currentStockLevel;
        System.out.println (productCode + ":" + " Received " +  currentStockLevel + "." + " Store Cost " + "$" + storeCost + "." + " New stock level: " + currentStockLevel);
    }
```

Comment: Always tag with the language. Create minimal test cases.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, i forgot it :)

Comment: Did you mean for your if statement to only execute one line or is this a typo?

Comment: If currentStockLevel is defined at object level then definately you can access this variable anywhere within the same instance method.

Comment: `currentStockLevel` is a field of your class. So any method of this class can access it.

Comment: Ah yeah thank you, i figured it out. I thought because of the void, it will not change the Value currentStockLevel so that it will only print it out and after finishing, it will stay 0 if i gave the value of currentStockLevel above to 0. Now i know that this is wrong, thanks again :).